# Can I dress specific dwarves in specific clothing?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this but:
**Is there any way to dress specific dwarves in specific clothing without using squads?**

I would like to dress my noble in a specific clothing.

Comment: Did one of the answers here solve your question? If so please mark one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **no**, except **maybe yes**, except **not really**.

Long answer:

- **No**, the game does not currently let you allocate clothes or other items that aren't rooms to specific dorfs. This is a serious pain in the tuchus when I want my miners to ditch their obsolete copper picks and use the exceptional-grade steel picks I painstakingly forged for them instead...
- However, it *is* possible to abuse the military subsystem and specify a very specific uniform to a specific dorf soldier, so there's the "**except maybe yes**"...
- Unfortunately, however, dorfs only respect the uniform settings when they're on military duty and will cheerfully ditch their uniform when they're off, so **not really**.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this by restricting the dwarf to a burrow with the new clothing and issuing Dump orders on his existing clothing. Being forcibly stripped by other dwarves will probably make him unhappy.